# Why won't this code save sortable list to new xml page?

Tags: php, jquery, sorting, save

I'm using Jquery UI's sortable code to load li elements from an external page. After the user reorders these elements, I would like to save the order to that same external page. What I am doing wrong?

Here's the relevant Javascript:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sortable').sortable({
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var newOrder = $('#sortable').sortable.toString();
            $.post('preview.php', {order:newOrder});
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Here's the PHP:

```
<?php

$neworder = $_POST('order');
file_put_contents('file.xml', $neworder);

?>
```

And here's the HTML:

```
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">


     <ul id="sortable">

  // populated via $("#sortable").load("file.xml"); //

        </ul>

    </div>
```

Comment: `$('#sortable').sortable.toString()` is incorrect, probably want `$('#sortable').sortable('serialize')` or `$('#sortable').sortable('toArray')`, but even that won't give you the original xml back.

Answer (score 2):

```
$_POST['order'];
```

not `$_POST('order');`

`$_POST` is an array of enviornment post variables..you want to access an index of it..

Comment: thanks, but my PHP script isn't even running. how do i make sure it runs when I reorder the list?

Comment: isn't even running means?? where is the problem?? is request going to php??